# Is there a countable computably saturated model of ZFC that correctly solves the halting problem?

Tags: set-theory, turing-machines, meta-math

We say that a model of ZFC $M$ correctly solves that halting problem if for every turing machine $T$, $T\text{ halts} \iff M \models T \text { halts}$.

Is there a countable computably saturated model of ZFC which correctly solves the halting problem? (See pg 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4450.pdf for what computably saturated means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. **Any** (consistent) theory (in a computable language) has computably saturated models, so just take $T$ to be (say) the theory ZFC + all true $\Pi_{17}$ statements of arithmetic. $T$ correctly decides (among other things!) whether the $e$th Turing machine halts, for each standard $e$, so any model of $T$ correctly solves the halting problem; now simply take an arbitrary computably saturated model of $T$.

---

Why do all appropriate theories have computably saturated models? Well, the point is that we only have to realize countably many types. Start with an arbitrary countable model $M$ of the theory, and list the computable types; at stage $s$, pass from the current model to a countable elementary extension realizing the $s$th computable type of that type is finitely consistent with the current model, and otherwise don't change the model - the union of this elementary chain will be a saturated model of the theory.

Comment: Why not True Arithmetic and just $\Pi_{17}$? And on that note, why not Zoidberg?

Comment: @AsafKaragila A gentleman doesn't invoke TA unless it's absolutely necessary. And Zoidberg is no gentleman - just look at all the times he's invoked TA when it's not absolutely necessary! (I mean, sure, they all happened off-screen, but that's no excuse for rude logic.)

Comment: I'm confused. You're claiming to be a gentleman? Or better than Zoidberg? :P

Comment: Cool. One consequence is that the set theoretic multiverse is not falsifiable via Turing machine (not that is was trying to be).

Comment: @PyRulez What do you mean by that? How would a Turing machine falsify the set-theoretic multiverse?

Comment: @NoahSchweber well, if a turing machine acts in such a way that is inconsistent with the multiverse axioms, that would falsify it. As an example, a machine finding a proof to 0=1 from ZFC halting would falsify ZFC+Con(ZFC).

Comment: @PyRulez Your example works since Con(ZFC) is an arithmetic statement. But the multiverse axioms aren't arithmetic, so I don't see how a Turing machine's behavior could falsify them. Can you describe a specific phenomenon you would consider an instance of a Turing machine falsifying the multiverse axioms?

Comment: @NoahSchweber well, your answer shows one does not exist. I was hoping the well foundness mirage would be testable, since it implies the natural numbers aren't actually well ordered (which should have implications for arithmetic).

Comment: @PyRulez On the contrary - in the first-order sense, the natural numbers not be well-orderable *doesn't* by itself have any implications for arithmetic: just consider a nonstandard elementary extension of $\mathbb{N}$ (which exists by compactness).

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah, true